# How do I do a <ContentPresenter>-like placeholder for a textbox <ControlTemplate>

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, blend

I'm trying to setup a control template for a textbox and to bind data to it. The problem is the data is not coming through. I thought since I have a textbox tag within the `<ControlTemplate>` that I needed to placeholder it somehow.

```
  <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="55" Background="White">
                    <Rectangle Stroke="#FFD9D9D9" StrokeThickness="6"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenterText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

So I experimented by adding a `<ContentPresenter>` tag but this throws an error.

Here's the textbox code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameTextField" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
```

Can anyone help me understand how to do this. A generic template that can be applied to all text fields where the data binding still works?

UPDATE: Here's the code it points to when crashes:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); //highlights this
        };
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it is not a good idea of putting a ContentPresenter inside of a TextBox .

If you use Control Template you should use Template binding to bind real component properties. The below code shows how can use it but as far as I remember TextBox does not have a property likes "Content", so you may transfer value of TextBox class's Text,Padding etc. as shown.

```
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <!--TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/-->
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

The output is 2,2,2,2 //ContentPresenter shows it in a TextBlock by default.

Beside this you override default things such as TextBox validation. If you would like to extend things I suggest override default style you can do it by right clicking a TextBox in blend and Edit Template-> Edit a Copy it generate current template for you by TextBox states,

default template is this,

```
   <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBorder"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadOnlyVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="ReadOnlyVisualElement" Background="#5EC9C9C9" Opacity="0"/>
                                <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#A5F7F7F7" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="1" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                                <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**ADDITION depend on your comment**:

```
     <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Grid x:Name="grid"  Background="White">
                <Rectangle Stroke="#FFD9D9D9" StrokeThickness="26"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenterText" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                </ContentPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer although I'm not sure I follow. In your example you used ContentPresenter? I'm just looking to style the box with a chunky border but notice you can't apply styles. I'm quite new really appreciate any explanation to even the most basic things :)

Comment: <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/> ContentPresenter be meaningful when you bind something to its Content property. To use it in a ControlTemplate your Control should have a Content property.By this way you pass it by using TemplateBinding. AFAIK TextBox doesn't have such a thing.

Comment: Ok I'm adding an addition to my answer for you to understand the essence

Comment: As you see on the ADDITION part I put a TextBox in contentpresenter to use it.Because use of ContentPresenter be meaningless because ContentPresenter purpose is just controls have Content (or its type object) property.

Comment: TextBox has "string Text " http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617604(v=vs.95).aspx